# Stored procedure to retrieve the query result as XML

Tags: java, xml, stored-procedures

Is it possible to retrieve the stored procedure result in XML format? I am using Java to call the stored procedure and Microsoft SQL Server management studio to test my stored procedures. Could someone provide a sample code?

Comment: Yes possible, is there any  question ?

Comment: Could you please let me know how to?

Comment: Check this link; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187508%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found something like this 

`SELECT
    CustomerID AS '@CustomerID',
    CustName AS '@Name',
    (SELECT ProductName AS '@productname'
     FROM dbo.Products p
     WHERE p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID

     FOR XML PATH('Product'), TYPE) AS 'Products',
    (SELECT HobbyName AS '@hobbyname'
     FROM dbo.Hobbies h 
     WHERE h.CUstomerID = c.CustomerID
     FOR XML PATH('Hobby'), TYPE) AS 'Hobbies'
FROM
    dbo.Customers c
FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT('Customers')`

Gives following output

```
<Customers>
  <Customer CustomerID="1" Name="Fred">
    <Products>
      <Product productname="Table" />
      <Product productname="Wardrobe" />
      <Product productname="Chair" />
    </Products>
    <Hobbies>
      <Hobby hobbyname="Golf" />
      <Hobby hobbyname="Swimming" />
    </Hobbies>
  </Customer>
  <Customer CustomerID="2" Name="Sue">
    <Products>
      <Product productname="CD Player" />
      <Product productname="Picture frame" />
    </Products>
    <Hobbies>
      <Hobby hobbyname="Dancing" />
      <Hobby hobbyname="Gardening" />
      <Hobby hobbyname="Reading" />
    </Hobbies>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Is this correct?